# SQL server - stored procedure - ignore exception

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have inside a stored procedure:

```
INSERT INTO SitesCategories(SiteID, CategoryID) VALUES(@SITEID, @TempCId);
```

This insert could throw exceptions because I have this constraint on the table:

```
  ALTER TABLE dbo.SitesCategories
    ADD CONSTRAINT UniqueSiteCategPair
    UNIQUE (SiteId,CategoryID);
```

I made this constraint so that I would not have to check when inserting the uniques of the pairs (@SITEID, @TempCId). But I do not want that an SQl exception is thrown when this gets executed inside the stored procedure. How can I "catch" the exception inside the stored procedure and continue operations inside the procedure ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you create your `UNIQUE CONSTRAINT` with the `IGNORE_DUP_KEY = ON` setting, then duplicates will be silently ignored, e.g. they won't be inserted into your table, but no exception will be thrown, either:

```
 ALTER TABLE dbo.SitesCategories
   ADD CONSTRAINT UniqueSiteCategPair
   UNIQUE (SiteId,CategoryID) WITH (IGNORE_DUP_KEY = ON);
```

Answer (score 6):

```
            BEGIN TRY
                INSERT INTO SitesCategories(SiteID, CategoryID) VALUES(@SITEID, @TempCId);
            END TRY
            BEGIN CATCH
            END CATCH;
```

Comment: Tnx Anja. So this is the way to catch exceptions in T-SQL. I chosen marc_s answer because it was exactly what I needed without knowing it :-)