# Using C#: Insert multiple values (not unique) into a field (Primary Key) in SQL database table?

Tags: database, c#-4.0, insert, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a table in SQL database which has two fields **Random** (Primary Key and not null) and **Count** (Identity increments by 1). I have to insert a billion records into Random field. I was able to insert 1000 rows at a time since that is the maximum an SQL Insert statement can handle (in C# console application using ADO.NET).

The data which I am trying to Insert is random but not unique. So, I have been getting the exception "Violation of Primary Key....". Instead of dropping only duplicate values all 1000 rows are being dropped.

**Is it possible to insert unique values by only dropping duplicate values not all records in insert statement (in my case 1000)?**

I have also tried using DataTable and SQLBulkCopy to insert the values with no success.

Example Scenario: TableA

Random  Count

100 1

101 2

Insert into (Random) TableA values (102),(103),(100),(104),(105),(101)

100 and 101 are duplicate values. Is there a way to drop only these values(100,101) and insert all other values (102,103,104,105)? (In my program, all values are being dropped because of primary key violation)

Any help on this is very much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try to make use of IGNORE_DUP_KEY flag. Remove PrimaryKey from Random and add a UNIQUE constraint as follows:

```
 ALTER TABLE dbo.TableA
   ADD CONSTRAINT UniqueRandomValue
   UNIQUE (Random) WITH (IGNORE_DUP_KEY = ON);
```

[SQL server - stored procedure - ignore exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7978279/sql-server-stored-procedure-ignore-exception)

The other option is writing your own logic to avoid or handle collisions. I'd advise using a stored procedure for such a case, in order to prevent repetitive db connections. Send a batch of data as parameter and insert them one by one within the stored procedure, ignoring the collisions. Be careful to limit batch size to avoid connection timeouts. Dynamically decreasing batch size proves useful for bouncing back from timeouts caused by data size.

```
BEGIN TRY
INSERT INTO TableA(Random) VALUES(@val);
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
END CATCH;
```